# Taking advantage of Swing double-buffering

Tags: java, swing, doublebuffered

I am writing a program that involves overriding a JPanel to do some graphics work. Basically this JPanel is displaying a field of hexagons and the user can interact with individual cells. This field is composed potentially of hundreds or thousands of hexagons, and most of the time when changes occur, only a tiny portion of the screen is affected. But at the same time, it uses multiple layers (there's a "main" layer that shows what the cells contain, and an overlay that shows which cells are selected and ready to be modified)

In order to avoid the cost of rendering each and every cell any time a repaint is needed, my app as it currently exists holds a BufferedImage for each layer. When paintComponent() is called, the app checks to see if any changes have been made that need to be drawn (for example, a user clicked on the screen so the overlay needs to show that some cell is selected), and if so, renders the modified layers to their bufferedimages. In either case, the the repaint just blits both of the BufferedImages to the screen.

It works just fine, but this is basically a home-spun version of double buffering, which Swing is supposed to support internally. However, for the life of me I can't seem to find where to get access to the component's backing buffer so that I can modify it... If I call "getGraphics()" on the JPanel, I get null pointer exceptions -- So that's a no-go.

I am looking for a more elegant elegant way to do this which hopefully takes advantage of the built-in double buffering offered by swing, in order to avoid blitting the entire screen just for one tiny change (and to avoid having to reinvent clipping).

Any ideas?

Comment: What you are doing is valid and reasonable. I wouldn't be worried about trying to get to the components backing buffer.  You could look at creating a sub image of the areas that have changed and simple painting those

Comment: Okay. Yeah my only other idea was to store an Area which tracks regions that have changed and then setting the clip to that, and just relying on that mysterious backing buffer to keep track of what hasn't changed... I just didn't want to do the work if there was a simpler way which I can't see there being... Thanks for the advice

Comment: Don't mess with the clip rectangle of the component, it will screw you over :P